# Why are not all icons displayed?

Tags: font-awesome

I'm using the current version of bootstrap and the current version of font aweson. 

Unfortunately, only some icons are displayed, some others not:

working are e.g. fa-envelope, fa-facebook, ...

**NOT** working is e.g. fa-address-book

Here is the snippet of the html code:

```
   <ul>
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-address-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Why is especially fa-address-book not shown?

How can I fix the problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

font-awesome has a css file that contains ***fa*** classes. So only updated font not worked with new icons and you must update css files of font-awesome.

You must be updating your css font to contains new icons like ***fa-address-book***:
https://andreas-peter.de/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css

font-awesome current css file that contains ***fa-address-book***: http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css

Comment: Thank you very much!
I just updated the css files and the font files and now everything is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

you supposed to use like this

```
<i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

more on http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't my problem. 
Mohammad Hamedani's solution fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to follow:

- Update the `font-awesome.css` file; the older version's CSS may not contain new fonts.
- Also update files inside your font folder. Download [font awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to hard-refresh your page